# Correctly redirect traffic from 80/443 to NodePort exposed Traefik 30080/30443 on Kubernetes using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, kubernetes

In a Kubernetes setting, Traefik is deployed as follows using `HelmRelease`:

```
apiVersion: helm.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: traefik-default
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  chart:
    repository: https://containous.github.io/traefik-helm-chart
    name: traefik
    version: 9.2.1
  releaseName: traefik-default
  values:
    ingressRoute:
      dashboard:
        enabled: false
    persistence:
      enabled: false
      accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      size: 100Mi
      storageClass: "ceph-replicated"
      path: /data
      annotations: {}
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 0
    additionalArguments:
      - "--log.level=INFO"
      - "--serverstransport.maxidleconnsperhost=0"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.delaybeforecheck=60"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.email=redacted"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.storage=/data/dns-cloudflare.json"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.email=redacted"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.storage=/data/tls.json"
      - "--providers.kubernetescrd.throttleduration=15"
      - "--accesslog=true"
    ports:
      traefik:
        expose: true
      web:
        port: 30080
        nodePort: 30080
      websecure:
        port: 30443
        nodePort: 30443
    service:
      type: NodePort
    nodeSelector:
      load-balancer: cloudflare
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "500m"
        memory: "100Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "1000m"
        memory: "250Mi"
```

I think the relevant facts are:

- In this 4-node cluster, only `node4` matches the node selector, therefore Traefik Pod runs on `node4` immediately after the above `HelmRelease` is `applied` on the Kubernetes cluster.
- Since I expose Traefik using `NodePort`, on all of the 4-nodes, these ports are open and accept traffic. `netstat -tunlp` confirms this:

```
...
tcp6       0      0 :::30080                :::*                    LISTEN      5050/kube-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::30443                :::*                    LISTEN      5050/kube-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::32100                :::*                    LISTEN      5050/kube-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::32709                :::*                    LISTEN      5050/kube-proxy
...
```

- I use the following `iptables` rules on all nodes (managed by `systemctl restart iptables-restore.service` tied to `/var/lib/iptables/rules-save`)

```
● iptables-restore.service - Restore iptables firewall rules
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables-restore.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2020-10-25 18:53:27 UTC; 17min ago
  Process: 31234 ExecStart=/sbin/iptables-restore -w -- /var/lib/iptables/rules-save (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31234 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

On the local network IP 10.1.44.40 corresponds to `node4` since it ends with a 40.
IP of `node1` on the local network is 10.1.44.10.
IP of `node2` on the local network is 10.1.44.20.
IP of `node3` on the local network is 10.1.44.30.

```
*filter
# Set default policies.
-F INPUT
-P INPUT DROP
# Enable loopback interface.
-A INPUT  -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
# Enable established connections.
-A INPUT -i br0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Disable fake pakages.
-A INPUT -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 255.255.255.255 -j DROP
-A INPUT -d 0.0.0.0 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 169.254.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 224.0.0.0/3 -j DROP
# Enable local IP addresses.
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
# Local services.
-A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 6443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 30000:32767 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p udp --dport 30000:32767 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
# Port 22 is rate-limited.
-I INPUT ! -s 10.0.0.0/8  -p tcp --dport 22 -i br0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i br0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 2 -j REJECT
# SYN-flood protection.
-A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
# Port-scan protection.
-A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
# Ping-of-death protection.
-A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.1.44.40 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.1.44.40 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# These I also tried.
# -A FORWARD -p tcp -d redacted-IP --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# -A FORWARD -p tcp -d redacted-IP --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
# This is for Traefik.
-A PREROUTING -p TCP -i br0 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 30443
-A PREROUTING -p TCP -i br0 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 30080
# These I also tried. Since local network IP ends with 40, this example iptables rules are for node4.
# -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.1.44.40:30080
# -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.1.44.40:30443
COMMIT
```

- Under `/etc/systemd/network` for each `node1-4` I have:

```
network # cat 10-bond0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
TransmitHashPolicy=layer2+3
MIIMonitorSec=1s
LACPTransmitRate=fast
```

```
network # cat 10-bond0.network
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

```
network # cat 15-br0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

```
cat 15-br0.network
[Match]
Name=bond0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

```
cat 20-static.network
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DNS=redacted-IP
Address=redacted-IP/24
Gateway=redacted-IP

Address=10.1.44.20/24 # As you can see, this is `node2`
```

All services are configured to the Traefik running on `node4`, so all services resolve to `node4` public redacted-IP.

Something is not quite right with the `iptables` rules, since:

- When a Pod A is running on `node4` (as well as Traefik is running on `node4`), that Pod A can never connect to any service by public redacted-IP to Traefik. Pod A gets Connection Refused.
- When a Pod B is running on any node but the `node4`, that Pod B can connect to any service by public redacted-IP to Traefik.
- Network is very hectic when it comes to accessing services exposed by Traefik from Pods that are running on the cluster. Connection attempts frequently getting dropped. It works however when the same services are called from a remote network.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Notable changes:

```
ports:
      traefik:
        expose: true
      web:
        port: 80
        nodePort: 30080
      websecure:
        port: 443
        nodePort: 30443
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop: [ ALL ]
        add: [ NET_BIND_SERVICE ]
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      runAsGroup: 0
      runAsNonRoot: false
      runAsUser: 0
```

```
apiVersion: helm.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  chart:
    repository: https://helm.traefik.io/traefik
    name: traefik
    version: 9.12.3
  releaseName: traefik
  values:
    deployment:
      kind: Deployment
    experimental:
      kubernetesGateway:
        enabled: false
    ingressRoute:
      dashboard:
        enabled: false
    persistence:
      enabled: false
      accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      size: 100Mi
      storageClass: "ceph-replicated"
      path: /data
      annotations: {}
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 0
    additionalArguments:
      - "--log.level=INFO"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.delaybeforecheck=60"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.email=redacted"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.storage=/data/dns-cloudflare.json"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.email=redacted"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.storage=/data/tls.json"
      - "--providers.kubernetescrd.throttleduration=15"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true"
    env:
      - name: CF_API_EMAIL
        value: redacted
      - name: CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY
        value: redacted
    ports:
      traefik:
        expose: true
      web:
        port: 80
        nodePort: 30080
      websecure:
        port: 443
        nodePort: 30443
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop: [ ALL ]
        add: [ NET_BIND_SERVICE ]
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      runAsGroup: 0
      runAsNonRoot: false
      runAsUser: 0
    hostNetwork: true
    service:
      type: NodePort
    nodeSelector:
      kubernetes.io/hostname: sigma04
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "1000m"
        memory: "200Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "2000m"
        memory: "400Mi"
```